# How to have the same date format in mongo and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, date, mongoose

I'm facing a problem. I'm working on calendar app. The problem is that after populating mongo db collection with days of the whole year, everything seems to be fine, but after fetching the data to the react front i'm ending with wrong date format and timezone. I've tried to debug it, and while fetching data with `Calendar.find({}, (err, calendar)) ...` the calendar seems like parsed with wrong date timezone. More below.

Ok, so this is the controller that populates database with days of the year:

```
exports.generateCalendar = (req, res) => {
    let days = [];
    for(let i=1; i<366; i++) {

        const dayOfTheWeek = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, i).getDay();
        if(dayOfTheWeek === 0 || dayOfTheWeek === 6){
            days.push({day: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, i), offWork: true, description: ' '});
        }
        else{
            days.push({day: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, i), offWork: false, description: ' '});
        }
    }

    Calendar.insertMany(days, (err) => {
        res.json('done');
    });
};
```

The output of this controller is collection of documents like that:

```
_id: 5cefc2e5c6db7f47401ba261
offWork: false
day: 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00
description: " "

_id: 5cefc2e5c6db7f47401ba262
offWork: false
day: 2019-01-02T00:00:00.000+01:00
description: " "
```

The next step is fetching the whole collection and sending it to the front in this simple controller:

```
exports.getCalendar = (req, res) => {
    Calendar.find({}, (err, calendar) => {
        if(err){
            res.json('Error while fetching data');
        }else{
            res.json(calendar);
            }

    })
};
```

However the output of fetching is:

```
{ offWork: false,
     _id: 5cefc2e5c6db7f47401ba261,
     day: 2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
     description: ' ',
     __v: 0 },
   { offWork: false,
     _id: 5cefc2e5c6db7f47401ba262,
     day: 2019-01-01T23:00:00.000Z,
     description: ' ',
     __v: 0 },
   { offWork: false,
     _id: 5cefc2e5c6db7f47401ba263,
     day: 2019-01-02T23:00:00.000Z,
     description: ' ',
     __v: 0 },
```

Which look like while fetching mongo is parsing the date including timezone offset.

I've created a for loop which pushes new date to a new array:

```
            let calendarArray = [];

                for(let i=0; i<calendar.length; i++){
                    calendarArray.push({day: calendar[i].day.toString(), offWork: calendar[i].offWork, description: calendar[i].description});
                }
                res.json(calendarArray);
```

And the output of this is correct on front-end but in wrong format:

```
Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)       
Wed Jan 02 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)       
Thu Jan 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
```

The perfect solution would be database in format YYYY-MM-DD or having the same date format in mongo and after fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, What I've done is I've installed moment.js and used it while pushing dates to new array and sending them to the front:

```
exports.getCalendar = (req, res) => {
    Calendar.find({}, (err, calendar) => {
        if(err){
            res.json('Error while fetching data');
        }else{
            let calendarArray = [];

                for(let i=0; i<calendar.length; i++){
                    calendarArray.push({_id: calendar[i]._id, day: moment(calendar[i].day).format("DD-MM-YYYY"), offWork: calendar[i].offWork, description: calendar[i].description, name: calendar[i].name});
                }

            res.json(calendarArray);
            }
    })
};
```

Not a perfect solution, but apparently, it's working.
If you have any other ideas how to solve this, I'd be glad to hear them.